# How to get latest 10 post feeds from facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I know this question has been addressed many times but I am still facing problems, So I wanted to ask here if anyone can help.

I used facebook SDK to get the latest posts, here is the code below:

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$pageFeed = $facebook->api(THE_PAGE_ID . '/feed');
```

Then I `print_r` the results but I am getting feeds like `[story]` which contains information like I have added someone as a friend or I have post somewhere, but there is also an attribute `[message]` which contains my reply on some post.

Now 1st thing I am getting only 4 feeds where is I want 10 feeds.
2nd thing is what information I shall extract to show on my website as latest post feeds (story, message or some other attribute)? Keeping in mind that I do not have both of these fields in every array.

If there is something I may not have mentioned here kindly do ask.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it page feed or your news feed ?

Comment: I am not sure about the difference between both but I need page feeds like everything that is being posted on facebook fan page. Right now am testing it using my facebook personal ID information

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `posts` instead of `feed` because feed includes user postings too.

You can test it in [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET) with `<your page id>/posts?limit=10` to get last 10 posts of your fanpage.

So your code should look like

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$pageFeed = $facebook->api(THE_PAGE_ID . '/posts?limit=10');
```